# hello, how do I modify to get the next node in the list only?

Tags: python, python-2.7

lets say list = [5,9,2,4,3] and I input Node = 9, only 2 will be output. Below is the code but currently, it output all the next element.

```
pos = list1.index(3) # list1 = [5,9,2,4,3]
i = pos+1
listLen = len(list1)
while i < listLen:
  print(list1[i])
  i+=1
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You need an if instead of a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with slice

```
list1 = [5, 9, 2, 4, 3]
try:
    pos = list1.index(9)
    print(*list1[pos + 1:pos + 2]) # get the slice and unpack (with *) the value
except ValueError:  # it is also advisable to handle the option of the absence of an element in the list
    print('No such item in the list')
```

Prints:

```
2
```